# Python - Find words in string

Tags: python, string

I know that I can find a word in a string with

```
if word in my_string:
```

But I want to find all "word" in the string, like this.

```
counter = 0
while True:
    if word in my_string:
        counter += 1
```

How can I do it without "counting" the same word over and over again?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make sure that it counts a full word like `is` will only have one in `this is` even if there is an `is` in `this`, you can split, filter and count:

```
>>> s = 'this is a sentences that has is and is and is (4)'
>>> word = 'is'
>>> counter = len([x for x in s.split() if x == word])
>>> counter
4
```

However, if you just want count all occurrences of a substring, ie `is` would also match the `is in this` then:

```
>>> s = 'is this is'
>>> counter = len(s.split(word))-1
>>> counter
3
```

in other words, `split` the string at every occurrence of the word, then minus one to get the count.

## Edit - JUST USE COUNT:

It's been a long day so I totally forgot but `str` has a built-in method for this `str.count(substring)` that does the same as my second answer but way more readable. Please consider using this method (and look at other people's answers for how to)

Comment: The second answer  was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `beg` argument for the `.find` method.

```
counter = 0
search_pos = 0
while True:
    found = my_string.find(word, search_pos)
    if found != -1: # find returns -1 when it's not found
        #update counter and move search_pos to look for the next word
        search_pos = found + len(word)
        counter += 1
    else:
        #the word wasn't found
        break
```

This is kinda a general purpose solution. Specifically for counting in a string you can just use `my_string.count(word)`

Answer (score 2):

String actually already has the functionality you are looking for. You simply need to use `str.count(item)` for example.

EDIT: This will search for all occurrences of said string including parts of words.

```
string_to_search = 'apple apple orange banana grapefruit apple banana'

number_of_apples = string_to_search.count('apple')
number_of_bananas = string_to_search.count('banana')
```

The following will search for only complete words, just split the string you want to search.

```
string_to_search = 'apple apple orange banana grapefruit apple banana'.split()

number_of_apples = string_to_search.count('apple')
number_of_bananas = string_to_search.count('banana')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re

word = 'test'
my_string = 'this is a test and more test and a test'

# Use escape in case your search word contains periods or symbols that are used in regular expressions.
re_word = re.escape(word)

# re.findall returns a list of matches
matches = re.findall(re_word, my_string)

# matches = ['test', 'test', 'test']
print len(matches) # 3
```

Be aware that this will catch other words that contain your word like `testing`.  You could change your regex to just match exactly your word